# include/linux/module.h:129:4: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] { return initfn; }

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I got the following warning(s) when I tried compiling a simple `Hello world` kernel module on the latest stable kernel release -

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/4.6.4'
  CC [M]  /root/LDD_EXAMPLES/chap02/hello.o
In file included from /root/LDD_EXAMPLES/chap02/hello.c:4:0:
/root/LDD_EXAMPLES/chap02/hello.c: In function ‘__inittest’:
include/linux/module.h:129:4: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  { return initfn; }     \
    ^
/root/LDD_EXAMPLES/chap02/hello.c:17:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘module_init’
 module_init(hello_init);
 ^
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /root/LDD_EXAMPLES/chap02/hello.mod.o
  LD [M]  /root/LDD_EXAMPLES/chap02/hello.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/4.6.4'
```

Code for the `Hello world` kernel module is as below -

```
#define DEBUG
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static const int __init hello_init(void)
{
    pr_debug("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    pr_debug("Goodbye world!\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Name <email.addr@domain.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple \"Hello world\" kernel module");
```

I never saw those warnings before when I tried running similar code on earlier versions of kernel (e.g. 3.0.3). Could someone please explain what am I doing wrong? Is it something wrong with my kernel configuration? Or has something changed in the latest releases of Linux kernel and my code needs to be tweaked accordingly?

Comment: Module's init function should have type `int (*)(void)`. In you case it is `const int (*)(void)`.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out. That indeed was the issue. Upon modifying the function signature, the source build alright without any warnings! :)